# Django ValueError: Cannot query "user": Must be "Profile" instance

Tags: django, listview, django-queryset, valueerror, instant-messaging

I am trying to add simple user to user messaging functionality to my blog app in Django. I have a view that allows a user to send a message but I am having difficulty in displaying the messages after. Here is my Message model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages_from')
    message = models.TextField(blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    unread = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

And the related Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is my MessagesView attempt:

```
class MessagesView(ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'users/messages.html'
    context_object_name = 'msg'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Profile.objects.filter(messages_from__isnull=False, messages__user_id=self.request.user)
```

And here is the url:

```
path('messages/<int:pk>/', MessagesView.as_view(), name='messages'),
```

Upon trying to load this page I receive the error `Cannot query "user": Must be "Profile" instance` where "user" is the name of the logged in user who's messages I am attempting to load. I have spent a long time googling a solution to this but have found nothing that relates to my case. Please help

Comment: Can you share the `Profile` model? The `MessagesView` should probably also return `Message` objects, not `Profile` objects.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding so fast. Post edited to show `Profile` model now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Message` has as `user` field a `ForeignKey` to `Profile`, not `User` (therefore it might be better to rename the field to `profile`). This thus means that filtering like `messages__user_id=self.request.user` does not make much sense.

You can filter by following the relation from `Profile` to `User` with:

```
class MessagesView(ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'users/messages.html'
    context_object_name = 'msg'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Profile.objects.filter(
            messages_from__isnull=False,
            messages__user__user=self.request.user
    ).distinct()
```

The [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) is necessary here to prevent retrieving the same `Profile` multiple times.

Since this is a `MessagesView`, you furthermore probably should return `Message`s, the fact that you set the `context_object_name` to `msg` also hints to that. In that case you thus should return a `QuerySet` of `Message`s, not `Profile`s:

```
class MessagesView(ListView):
    model = Message
    template_name = 'users/messages.html'
    context_object_name = 'msg'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Message.objects.filter(
            user__user=self.request.user
        )
```

In case you rename the `ForeignKey` to `profile`, you filter with `profile__user=self.request.user`.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).